# How to bypass Firefox restriction to show external widget?

Tags: javascript, security, firefox

I've got a `<script />` from external domain in my html template that is poll widget.
Unfortunately, some of my users that use Firefox in strict privacy mode can't see it because of Firefox restrictions.
How can I bypass that restriction or at least show some sort of notification?

At the picture you can see the exact setting that blocks the widget.
[image]

Comment: You can't. It's my browser, and my choises, and if you'll ever manage to pop up a blocked tracker on my browser, I'll navigate away from your site and will never come back.

Comment: @Teemy, maybe it's possible then to detect such users and show them notifications i.e. "please, add our site to exceptions to see our content"?

Comment: I hope not, as I would had seen more than 80,000 "Please let us track" notifications lately ...

Comment: well, I'm sorry to dissapoint you then. It seems I've found the way to detect this setting.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/doNotTrack